# How to wait for QProgressDialog construction?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qprogressdialog

Before long operation is executed, I'm invoking `QProgressDialog` to inform user about the progress of the execution. The long operations is waiting for thread to be terminated.

The problem is, when I use `show` method of `QProgressDialog`, the progress dialog is not fully constructed and the thread goes into the `wait` method of the thread, as you can see on the figure below:

[image: 1]

Meanwhile when I use `exec` method of the `QProgressDialog`, the progress dialog is fully constructed, but the `wait` method is not invoked until I exit the progress dialog, as you can see here:

[image: 2]

This is the code I'm using:

```
auto dialog = new QProgressDialog();
dialog->setWindowTitle("Wait");
dialog->setLabelText("Aborting optimization");

dialog->resize(100, 30);
dialog->show();

optimizerUi->terminate();
optimizerUi->wait();

dialog->hide();
```

Is there any way I can wait for or force the progress dialog to be fully constructed before the thread falls into the `wait` method, which takes quite a long time and blocks the main thread? Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: What kind of object  is optimizerUi? You want to have its terminate method emit a signal, then connect that signal to the close method of your dialog. Blocking the UI by calling wait is not good.

Comment: I don't think your dialog is not fully constructed, but `wait()` is executing, blocking the dialog from updating the view. Both `exec()` and `wait()` block the main thread, so you cannot run both at the same time.

Comment: @Botje `optimizerUi` is a `QThread`. It takes a while before it is terminated because its performing complex operation. @NgocMinhNguyen Alright, then I have to use `show()` method of the `dialog`, but then the dialog has no content, is there any way I can show the dialog properly and then terminate the thread (and call `wait()`)? Thanks for replies.

Comment: I suppose I can connect `QThread::finished()` signal to `dialog.hide()` slot, and don't call `wait()` at all, just disable appropriate button(s) until thread's `finished` signal is emitted.

Comment: Indeed. Letting the signals do the work for you is the proper way. Never block the event loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for the thread to finish with some timeout. If the thread is finished, close the progress dialog. If it isn't, process the application events.

```
auto dialog = new QProgressDialog();
dialog->setWindowTitle("Wait");
dialog->setRange(0, 0);
dialog->setLabelText("Aborting optimization");
dialog->setCancelButton(nullptr);

dialog->resize(100, 30);
dialog->show();

optimizerUi->terminate();
while (!optimizerUi->wait(QDeadlineTimer{100}))
{
    QApplication::processEvents();
}
dialog->hide();
```